# Adding several properties with one CASE/FOREACH -statement in Cypher

Tags: foreach, neo4j, cypher, case

I'm trying to create a relationship with properties depending on several different cases. I thought I could use FOREACH and CASE.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///hwconnectIDs.csv' AS cnct
MATCH (h1:hardware), (h2:hardware), (c:cable)
WHERE (h1.hwID= cnct.conID1) AND (h2.hwID = cnct.conID2) AND (c.cableID =cnct.cableID)
FOREACH ( plugType IN 
          CASE WHEN (h1.plug1=c.plug1 AND c.plug2=h2.plug1) 
               THEN [c.plug1,c.plug2]
          CASE WHEN (h1.plug2=c.plug2 AND c.plug1=h2.plug1)
               THEN [c.plug2,c.plug1]
          ELSE [] END
          | 
          CREATE (h1)<-[:connect{plug:plugType[0]}]-(c)-[:connect{plug:plugType[1]}]->(h2) 
         )
```

Problems:

- It seems I cannot create an array-type variable *plugType* in FOREACH
- For the ELSE-case I would like to not create the relationship at all. Right now, the value for the relationship-properties *plugType* would just be empty rather than the whole relationship not existing.

Note: The WHERE-condition insures that I am working with the correct hardware-devices and cable. The file *hwconnectIDs.csv* basically gives a list of devices *h1* and *h2* meant to be linked by cable *c*.

Is there a way of executing commands according to several different cases in Cypher like *if/elseif/../else* in other languages?

Comment: Do you get an error message or similar?

Comment: I had one before. But when I tried this just now, I didn't get one. It just said "(no changes, no records)".

Comment: Are you certain that the nodes referenced in your `MATCH` statement exist?

Comment: and, of course, satisfy the `WHERE` conditions for some or all lines in your csv file?

Comment: I tried finding the nodes satisfying the WHERE-condition and got exactly the nodes that I wanted. However: Afterwards when I tried the above query I got this error: "`RJ45` is not a collection or a map. Element access is only possible by performing a collection lookup using an integer index, or by performing a map lookup using a string key (found: RJ45[0])". Which is the same I had before. RJ45 is one of the plugTypes.

Comment: Edit: If I replace my CREATE-command above with 
"CREATE (:plugType{content:plugType})" 
and then MATCH all nodes with label "plugType"  (which didn't exist before) I get two nodes with each having one entry RJ45 in content, rather than one having an array [RJ45,RJ45] as value for content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to leverage the WITH clause for this (simplified things below) :

```
...
WITH h1, h2, c, 
CASE 
WHEN (h1.plug1=c.plug1 AND c.plug2=h2.plug1) THEN [c.plug1,c.plug2]
WHEN (h1.plug2=c.plug2 AND c.plug1=h2.plug1) THEN [c.plug2,c.plug1]
ELSE [] END AS plugtype
CREATE ...
```

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: I thought about that as well. The problem is: I don't actually have the cable node yet. My data model is such that it only makes sense to create the cable nodes as part of a relation between two devices, so in my code I create the cable just before I create the relationship. Maybe I should try separating the cable-creation and the relationship-creation so I can reference the cables.

Comment: Well, if the file - as I think I understand from your explanation - contains the actual connections (so when a cable should be created) run through it once to create those and do the relationships in a second run. You can do it all in one go ... but even with millions of nodes going through it twice doesn't take that long and you'll have two simpler queries instead of one complicated query. Make sure to create constraints on hwID and cableID beforehand though.

Comment: I got my query running with the above code. Although I did have to create the cables first which caused some other problems. I'm working around that with py2neo now.